# Strange spacing in HTML

Tags: css, html, spacing

I have strange problems developing a [site](http://universal-office.com.ua).

Any browser on my computer adds a spacing above some elements at the page (e.g. above the navbar, the dropdown in navbar, the container etc). In the Chrome Developer Tool it displays like having a strange `text` element (quotes with spacing):
[image: 1]

but in source code it displays without it:
[image: 2]

If I delete that quotes from the Tool, the spacing disappears.

That quotes (spacing) can't be added by Javascript or PHP: it exists ever it we comment all script includes and disable php preprocessing for `.html` files ([example](http://www.universal-office.com.ua/index_noscript.html)).
This spacing can't be added by CSS: e.g. for navbar we have rule:

```
.navbar {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

The spacing exists in all browsers at my computer (tested in Firefox, Chrome, IE 9).

Moreover, Firefox Dev Tool doesn't display any quotes:
[image: 3]

but adds spacing in code in that places where are quotes in Chrome Dev Tool.

So, what's it? How to remove this spacing (I don't want to use ugly solutions like negative margin)?

Please comment do you have this problem on your machine? Thanks.

Comment: Haha, I was about your age when I started PHP, too!  I am now 21 and I have had a successful career in programming.  It's a great job :)  Keep it up, good luck.

Comment: If you have copied and pasted your Html from somewhere, then it is possible that you have copied some hidden characters. This is a known problem when copying from jsfiddle into visual studio.

Comment: @Jon:  Yeah, it's successful so far in that I've gained a lot of experience and I've made a lot of money...  get off my back lol.

Comment: @TimBJames I've wrote it by myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me, that the spaces are 'special spaces' like `&nbsp;` is one. They may look like a normal space character, even in a text editor

Look at the code, which generates the HTML structure. 
Then delete the spaces in request. Put back the formating spaces by using the space bar key.

---

edit

looking closer in my text editor i realised, you have a special diacritical character in your code.

When you look a my screen from Notepad++ editor, there are small 'hooks' at the less than character (`<`) of the `<nav>` and the `<li>` tag which I marked red.

Don't just delete the spaces, delete the less than character (`<`) too and retype it using the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Good catch. I've experienced this problem myself and that's a tough one to find.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. I could not target a div with a selector and wondered a day why it did not work. A hidden barely visible character was the issue. Great help!

Answer (score 3):

The characters between the `<body>` and `<nav>` elements are a line feed and a BOM - Byte Order Mark (aka zero width non-breaking space) U+FEFF (EF BB BF in UTF-8). See the image below taken from Hex editor Neo

[image]

It's the BOM that you need to remove.

Answer (score 1):

There is whitespace in your source HTML: between the `<body>` and `<nav>`. The only way to make it go away is by running the two tags together, as in

```
<body><nav class="..."> ... </nav></body>
```

HTML dictates that runs of whitespace outside of attribute values are treated as one single space, so it doesn't really matter how much whitespace there is, if it's newlines or not, etc. Even if you have a single space character in your HTML, a conformant browser has to treat it as a text node. It's these text nodes that Chrome hints to by showing the quotes.

Comment: It's entirely possible that you can just delete some unseen whitespace in there as well, but if that doesn't work, then yeah, try sticking the tags directly next to each-other.

Comment: whitespace shouldn't do anything, because `<body>` is `display: block` and `<nav>` is also `display: block`